# Dragon Ball FighterZ character DLC options

Tags: nintendo-switch, dragon-ball-fighterz

I have **Dragon Ball FighterZ** for Nintendo Switch, and I am considering adding some fighter characters via DLC. But I am finding the options a little confusing.

There are the following products (not counting the original game Dragon Ball FighterZ itself):

- FighterZ Pass
- FighterZ Pass 2
- FighterZ Pass 3
- FighterZ Edition
- Ultimate Edition*

<sup>`*` = Currently discounted in eShop</sup>

The last two on this list confuse me most.

I haven't purchased any DLC yet, but do own the original game. In order to get additional characters, what are my options? I don't want to pay twice for duplicate characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [eShop page](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/dragon-ball-fighterz-switch/), FighterZ Edition includes the original game and FighterZ Pass, and Ultimate Edition includes the original game, FighterZ Pass, Anime Music Pack (11 songs from the Anime) and Commentator Voice Pack.

Both of the special edition doesn't comes with FighterZ pass 2 and 3, so if you want to have all of the characters, then buy either of the FighterZ edition or Ultimate edition plus FighterZ pass 2 and 3, or just buy all of the FighterZ pass without buying any special edition then you're good to go.